# Destruction policy for `std::unique_ptr<Base>(ptr)` when I don't know how `ptr` was allocated?

Tags: c++, memory-management, smart-pointers

Another "modern C++" beginner question. I seem to have some misconception about how to properly use smart pointers / smart pointer destruction policies.

```
struct Base {
    virtual Base* clone() const = 0;
    virtual ~Base() { }
};

void clone_and_use(const Base &original) {
    auto clone = std::unique_ptr<Base>(original.clone());
    …  // do something with `clone`
}
```

As far as I can tell, when `clone` goes out of scope, the pointed-to memory will be `delete`d thanks to the `std::default_delete<Base>` destruction policy used by `std::unique_ptr<Base>` (which appears to be equivalent to `std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Base>>`).

What if `original.clone()` returned a pointer to memory that was *not* allocated with `new`? Obviously the standard `std::default_delete<Base>` destruction policy would be inappropriate—`delete` should only be used together with `new`, but not with `new[]`, `malloc`, or anything else— and I should specify a different destruction policy when I create the `clone` smart pointer… but which one would I specify?

```
    auto clone = std::unique_ptr<Base, ?>(original.clone());
    //                                 ^
```

I am guessing that I would have to extend `Base` such that I can simply ask any derived type to provide a destruction policy suitable for its `clone()` implementation, but I'm not exactly sure how I would do this.

Can someone show me how to:

- Define the `Base` interface such that it can support a `clone()` method without leading to leaked or incorrectly freed memory; and
- How to properly work with smart pointer destruction policies (if they are necessary at all in this example)?

Comment: You can use something like `std::unique_ptr<Base, std::function<void(Base*)>>` for a fully dynamic deleter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `clone()` should return a smart pointer appropriately, i.e.

```
virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() {
...
}
```

This avoids all ambiguity.

Comment: That was my first guess, but how can `clone()` possibly know what kind of ownership is desired by the caller?

Comment: @stakx If the caller wants different ownership they can call `.release()`.  The huge advantage to returning a smart pointer here is that it removes the possibility of leaks.

Comment: eh? I think if your caller cares about ownership - they will take ownership of the object returned by clone (in the above case by *moving* it to it's own internal member for example..) or if it doesn't care, let it go out of scope and cleanup automatically...

Comment: @Nim: Thank you, returning a `unique_ptr` is what I shall do then. Seems I was misled by [this FAQ on isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/virtual-functions#virtual-ctors), which suggests a `clone` function returning a raw pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Just have `Base` define a `clone` method that returns the smart pointer with the correct deleter.

```
void clone_and_use(const Base& original) {
  auto clone = original.Clone();
  ... // do something with `clone`
}

std::unique_ptr<Base, BaseDeleter> Clone() const {
    return std::unique_ptr<Base, BaseDeleter>(new Base(this));
}
```

Alternatively, you can override `std::default_delete` for your type.

```
namespace std
{
   template<>
   class default_delete<Base>
   {
   public:
      void operator()(Base* ptr)
      {
         // Do delete operation on `ptr`
      }
   };
 }
```

Comment: But how can `clone` know what mode of ownership is desired by the caller?

Comment: @stakx It doesn't. By returning a `std::unique_ptr`, the caller has to own the returned pointer. They can give up ownership if they would like, but they can't request an unowned pointer.

Answer (score 1):

> What if original.clone() returned a pointer to memory that was not allocated with new?

If you don't know how to deallocate it, you cannot deallocate it, with or without help from any smart pointer class. Therefore you cannot take ownership of it in any shape or form.

> How to properly work with smart pointer destruction policies

You cannot work with unknown policies. How to properly work with smart pointer destruction policies in *your* class? Easy: it's *your* class. Make the policy known. Decide on one policy and document your decision, thus everyone who writes a derived class must obey. Alternatively, add an output-argument `std::function& deletePolicy` to `clone`, then wrap `clone` in a convenience function that returns a `unique_ptr`.